# append a transformation to an existing transformation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element

```
<g class="annot" transform="translate(317,15)">...</g>
```

which I obtain using

```
$('g.annot')
```

I would like to scale it, eg

```
$('g.annot').css({'transform': 'scale(2)'})
```

But this causes the translate position to be reset.

How can I apply *scale* and retain *translate*

Answer (score 1):

Just concat the attribute with the next transformation:

```
let g = $('g.annot');
g.attr('transform', `${g.attr('transform')} scale(2)`);
```

or use the [svg api](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGTransformable)

```
let 
  g = $('g.annot').get(0),
  root = g.ownerSVGElement,
  mtr = root.createSVGMatrix(),
  t = g.transform.baseVal
;

mtr.a = 2;
mtr.d = 2;

t.appendItem(root.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(mtr))
```

Comment: Tried it on both safari 12 and FF 68 but not working and let g = $('g.annot') ~ undefined

Comment: is the svg within the dom? what about: `document.querySelector('g.annot')` ?

Comment: still undefined .. its identifiable but not assignable to a variable

Comment: That is a diffrent issue. There are a lot of reasons why you get undefined here, do run the code after the load event, is the node actually in the DOM etc. The code have given above does not show that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var trans = $('g.annot').attr('transform');
$('g.annot').attr(trans+' scale(2)');
```